# Swapping the digits of an algebraic number (e.g. $\sqrt 2$)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

Let an algebraic number, say $ a=\sqrt 2 = 1.41421356237309504880...$, and define

$$b=f(a)=1.14243165323790058408...$$

by swapping the digits $a_{2i+1}$ and $a_{2i+2}$ for $i≥0$, corresponding to the decimal part of $a$ (we consider the decimal expansion, i.e. in base $10$).

My question is:

> Is it true (or at least suspected) that $b$ is also algebraic?

It is not difficult to show that $y=f(x)$ is rational iff $x$ is, because a rational number has a finite or a periodic decimal expansion, and $f(f(x))=x$. This is why I chose an irrational algebraic number $a = \sqrt 2$.

Here are related questions : [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/971137/changing-digits-of-an-irrational-allowed?rq=1), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876532/do-replacing-distinct-digits-from-distinct-places-of-an-algebraic-irrational), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136518/can-permutating-the-digits-of-an-irrational-transcendental-number-give-any-other).

For instance, the number $a'=0.1010010001000010000010000001...$ is [transcendental](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778218/is-0-1010010001000010000010000001-ldots-transcendental), and I believe that $f(a')$ is also transcendental.

Maybe this could be related to the (suspected) normality of irrational algebraic numbers, like $\sqrt 2$... I looked at Liouville's theorem, but I wasn't able to conclude.

Any comment will be appreciated !

Comment: I see no reason to think that swapping digit would conserve a number's algebraic-ness. Swapping digit is such a random thing to do, and I'd say that $f(\sqrt{2})$ is almost certainly transcendental.

Comment: @vrugtehagel : this is also what I think… but I don't know how it could be proven. I believe that this can be a difficult problem…

Comment: Yes, unless there is an *algebraic* definition for this operation, it seems highly unlikely to be the case. Hard to prove, though, because it is hard to prove things aren't algebraic, in general.

Comment: More generally, you might ask: If $10x+y$ is algebraic, for $x,y$ real, then is $x+10y$? This is equivalent to asking whether $x-y$ is algebraic, which is thus equivalent to asking whether $x$ is algebraic. So you can rephrase whether taking every other digit $1.01020\dots$ is algebraic.

Comment: Another question, similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992497), would be to know whether _exchanging_ the digits $0$ and the digits $1$ (e.g. $0.1002301…$ becomes $0.0112310…$) preserves transcendence.

Comment: Possibly related (?) : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/283331